# Twitter Bootstrap renders differently with linebreaks around HTML elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The issue I am reporting here has been driving me nuts because I thought it was a CSS issue. Turns out that Bootstrap renders one of my forms differently depending on whether the HTML has linebreaks in it or not. In one instance, the controls are rendered with no visible space between them, and in the other they are nicely spaced.

You can see the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/JTvH7/1/

In the code, the form is repeated twice. The markup is identical except that the first version is all on a single line, the second version is tidied up and has line breaks between the elements.

```
<form><div class="form-horizontal"><select id="species"><option value="cat">Cat</option><option value="dog">Dog</option></select><button class="btn btn-primary">Next&nbsp;<i class="icon-chevron-right icon-white"></i></button><button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button></div></form>

<form>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <select id="Select2">
            <option value="cat">Cat</option>
            <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Next&nbsp;<i class="icon-chevron-right icon-white"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: rendered output]

I really want to auto-generate some of my HTML (using jQuery .html) which means I will get the all-on-one-line version injected onto my page, and hence incorrect rendering. An ugly, basic workaround is to put `&nbsp;` between the controls, but I very much want to avoid this.

Has anyone encountered and overcome this issue? I am tempted to report it in Bootstrap's github.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that browsers interpret spaces, linebreaks and tabs as a single space. So this is the same as to have `&nbsp;` between them.

The right way to position buttons is to use css. E.g. bootstrap has `.btn-toolbar` class for buttons. You just need to add some css rule for select.

```
.btn-toolbar > select + .btn {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JTvH7/2/

Comment: Thanks very much! I wasn't aware of the linebreak being interpreted as a space but thought anything outside an element was ignored. Makes a lot more sense now.